# How to override the default autocomplete settings in Sublime Text 2 with a user snippet?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

If you start to type `<ul>`, it will autocomplete if you press tab and you get `<ul></ul>`. Since there is almost never a time when I won't have any list items, I have created a snippet for "ul" on tab that will return:

```
<ul>
    <li>${1}</li>
</ul>
```

So far, I can't get ti to work since it goes back to the default. Also, I often have to use lots of classes or other attributes that I'd like to add in as autocomplete like:

```
<div class="${1}" id="${2}"></div>
<input class="${1}" type="${2}" ${3:required} ${4:disabled} />
```

etc. How do you achieve this type of functionality?

Comment: If you install [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime), you could do something like ul>li*5 to get a ul with 5 li's. See the [cheat sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) for more uses.

Comment: I already have Emmet but that isn't really where I was going. It's true that your comment answers a perfectly (and easy) way to achieve the first section of my issue, but it doesn't easily answer the second part. For now, I've assigned key bindings for the snippets I really need but that isn't a great solution since I'm used to starting the actual tag and not some strange key command that I will get used to and then later when not using my machine I will have a heck of a time working without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to comment out the "ul" and "UL" triggers in this file:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-completions
```

Comment: Strange. I tried deleting them and editing them to what I wanted but neither worked. I didn't try commenting them out. I actually think this is an issue with Emmet that I have installed, though.

Comment: Right, it's coming from Emmet.  I had to disable Emmet, to remove the ul completion.